# cumulative formula for car mileage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to figure out how to calculate a formula for a cumulative variable as follows:

If a car company is able to produce and deliver 60 units of car model X every 3 months, spread out over the 3 months, delivering the first 2 cars on day 3, the next 2 cars on day 6 and so on, and each car can drive 500 miles per day at 90% usage, and considering there are already 200 cars in the market, at which point in time from today will the mileage of car model X reach N number of miles?

It's been a while since I did this kind of math in primary school and I can't figure out how to calculate it anymore.

Comment: Are the deliveries all on the same day, or are they spread out through the $3$ months?  Compute the number of cars on the road as a function of the day, then add them up.  The sum of an arithmetic series will be useful.

Comment: Spread out. Thanks

Comment: The problem is still not well specified.  They deliver two cars every three days.  Which of the first three days do they deliver cars on?  Is the three day pattern then repeated? Before you answer a question you need to know what the question is.

Comment: Spread out over the 3 months, delivering the first 2 cars on day 3, the next 2 cars on day 6 and so on.

Comment: Apologies that this is taking long to define. I am not very experienced in using the site...

Comment: It is not this site, it is making sure you have all the information to solve the problem.  In my first comment I suggested you compute the number of cars on the road each day.  You need to make sure you have enough information to do that.  You should click the edit button below your question and update it so people don't have to go through the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we know how the cars are delivered, we know that on day $k$ there are $200+2\lfloor \frac k3 \rfloor$ cars on the road.  On day $k$ they accumulate $100\ 000+1000 \lfloor \frac k3 \rfloor$ miles, assuming cars can drive on the day they are delivered.  By day $N$ the original fleet has accumulated $100\ 000N$ miles.  The new cars get $0,0,1000,1000,1000,2000,2000,2000,3000\ldots$ miles.  If $N \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ we go through $\lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor$ groups of three evenly, accumulating $1000\cdot 3 \cdot \frac 12 \lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor\left(\lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor-1 \right)$ miles.  If $N \not \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ we need to add on the last day or two.  This gives the mileage as $$\begin {cases}
100\ 000 N + 1000\cdot 3\cdot \frac 12 \lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor\left(\lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor-1 \right) & N \equiv 2 \pmod 3\\100\ 000 N + 1000\cdot 3 \cdot \frac 12 \lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor\left(\lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor-1 \right) +\frac {1000N}3& N \equiv 0 \pmod 3\\100\ 000 N + 1000\cdot 3\cdot \frac 12 \lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor\left(\lfloor \frac {N+1}3 \rfloor-1 \right)+\frac{2000(N-1)}3 & N \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \end {cases}$$